# Eloquent returns error on saving a username/password

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In my db, an admin creates an account for a user, but doesn't fill in their username/password. Once this row has been created, then the user will get an email that asks them to register.

In my `store()` of my `RegisterController`, after I perform all the validation, I have the following:

```
// here $user is received via authorization code and email

$user->username = $input['username'];
$user->password = $input['password'];
if ($user->save()) $data;
return 'Could not save';
```

However, this gives me an error saying `Trying to get property of non-object`. I also realize that you need to `Hash` the password, but I have built on the `Model` and it will automatically hash the `password` attribute inside.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure `$user` containts an instance of an Eloquent Model, because the error suggests the it's not an object. Try `dd($user)` and see what you get.

Comment: No it is. I thought that too. I followed the code, and I does eventually go into the `Model.php` and the `save(array $options = array())` is called. It then fails on `$saved = $this->performUpdate($query);` line

Comment: So I followed the code further through and it fails on `fireModelEvent('updating'). Something fails, and from the description, it is a validation of some sort. The funny thing is if I override the validation, everything does go through fine, and everything is saved.

Comment: What's the line in the controller that throws `Trying to get property of non-object`, is it the one with `$user->save()`?

Comment: If you have `debug` enabled, Laravel should give you the the entire execution stack trace and exact line the application fails on.

Comment: Could we please see your User model class?